# Custom JavaScript functions from Java: doesn't work with explicit context?

Tags: java, javascript

#### PreWork

I am able to invoke or evaluate javascript expressions from java as follows:

```
jsEngine.eval("ComputerName == 'mymachine'", myScriptContext);
```

The attribute value ComputerName is read from myScriptContext object.

#### Scenario

Now the problem is that I want to have some custom functions which can be part of the evaluated expression like:

```
jsEngine.eval("startswith(ComputerName, 'my')", myScriptContext);
```

Since startswith is not an available function (I must support startswith with that signature), I tried to write a .js file, where I defined my custom functions & also appended my expression to be evaluated to that script and executed as follows:

```
jsEngine.eval("_js_having_myfunction_and_expression_"); // note - no myScriptContext
```

#### Problem

`startswith` gets recognized by JS engine ONLY IF I DO NOT present myScriptContext. The moment I present myScriptContet, I get this exception:

Exception in thread "main":

> javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: startswith is not a function

Comment: Perhaps you could try doing `jsEngine.eval("startswith = function(x, y) { ... };")` in order to manually define the function in your JS execution context prior to when you try to invoke it?

Comment: I'm guessing by the exception that you're using Rhino... is that correct? If so, where are you trying to run this Javascript — ie in a browser, on a webserver, in a desktop app?

Comment: This is executed as a server side business logic.

Comment: @aroth That would work if the consecutive eval() calls are made WITHOUT any ScriptContext. I have tried that aswell & found that, the moment the ScriptContext is given in the 2nd call for eval(), it will run in a different context and does't understand custom functions passed for 1st call of eval().

Comment: And yes. It is using the default Rhino that comes with Java6.

Comment: If you are making multiple calls to eval() then you would want to use your 'myScriptContext' for each call to ensure that all of your previous javascript values/functions are available to each subsequent script you execute.

Comment: Yes. I did the same by having the same scriptcontext object for successive calls to eval() but that didn't work either!

Comment: Do you have an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) you could post?

Comment: I evaluate my custom function initially:
javaScriptEngine.eval("function startswith(str, substr) {\r\n"
    + " return str.indexOf(substr) == 0;\r\n" + "};");
Then the following 2 eval()s work:
// WORKS
  System.out.println(javaScriptEngine.eval("startswith('abcd', 'ab'); "));
  // WORKS
  javaScriptEngine.put("key", "blue");
  System.out.println(javaScriptEngine.eval("startswith(key, 'bl')"));

Comment: the following code block doesn't work
// DOES NOT WORK
  Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
  props.put("name", "blue");
  ScriptContext ctx = new MyScriptContext(props);
  System.out.println(javaScriptEngine.eval("startswith(name, 'bl')", ctx));

Comment: With your custom function evaluation you do not have the 'ctx' object as a parameter. That is what i said in my previous comment. You need to pass that 'ctx' object to each call to eval() if you want it to know what happened in previous calls to eval().

Comment: I tried that as well. But that did not work.